# JavaScript doesn't include value in list item

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Playlist</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="songInput" placeholder="Enter a song">
    <input type="button" id="songButton" value="Add to Playlist">
  </form>

  <ul id="playlist">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The above html is linked to the following javascript:

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
  var button=document.getElementById("songButton");
  button.onclick=handleSongButtonClick;
}

function handleSongButtonClick(){
  var input = document.getElementById("songInput");
  var songName = songInput.value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.value=songName;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

What is the problem when i enter a song all it gives is a bullet and no text value? Please help it can be found here http://jsbin.com/EROcOGo/2/edit

Comment: You'd be surprised how little "not working" does to describe your issue.

Comment: List items don't have a value property, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `innerText`

```
function handleSongButtonClick(){
  var input = document.getElementById("songInput");
  var songName = input.value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText=songName; // Change here
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

[**Modified jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/eMICESU/2/)

Answer (score 2):

The `.value` property is typically only useful with `<form>`-related elements -- `<input>`, `<textarea>`, etc.

```
li.value = songName; // has no affect
```

To set the text content within other elements, you can either:

- Set [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) (standard) and `.innerText` (IE):

  ```
  li.textContent = li.innerText = songName;
  ```
- [Create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) a text node.

  ```
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(songName));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input.value` instead of `songInput.value;`

```
li.innerText=songName;
```

instead of

```
li.value=songName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it: http://jsbin.com/UzeZasa/3/edit?html,js,output

First `songInput` wasn't declared (was named only `input`.
Second: `value` isn't an attribute of `li`. You have to set the inner-html of that tag with `element.innerHTML = content`.